# Programmatically Knowing the App name using WiFi

Tags: android, android-wifi

I want to know which of my application is currently using WiFi. I got one way by programmatically reading the android manifest file of each app and searching whether the permission `android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE` is declared. But that does not tell me whether the app is currently using WiFi or not though it has the permission.So I need another way to detect which of my currently running app is using WiFi.

If this is possible Can i know the data that is being sent from my device using the WiFi connection

Comment: Have you got answer for this question?

Comment: Thanks. Can you please direct me to that link or post any sample code.

Comment: Can U tell me what exactly is your need ? May be I can be precise then..

Comment: I want to know whether application is using wifi now or not. If it is using wifi I want to fetch amount of usage and wifi signal strength during the data transmission(or receiving).

Comment: Check the Answer given..